# Natural Language Understanding (NLU) No Concepts Returned

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-nlu, nlu

I am extracting Concepts using IBM Watson Natural Language Understanding (NLU) API. For most texts it is able to extract at least 1 or 2 Concepts, however in some simple cases it returns no Concept.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, CategoriesOptions, ConceptsOptions, RelationsOptions

natural_language_understanding = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1( version='2018-11-16', iam_apikey='API-KEY', url='https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api')

post ="No job Never had any romantic experiences I just have no ability / infrastructure to get through life It's killing me I don't want to be part of this world because I can't fit in, can't compete, can't enjoy Why does it have to be so uncomfortable? I feel so sad on the inside Another night I wonder how it will ever change, will it require my effort completely? I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO FUCKING DO"

response = natural_language_understanding.analyze(
    text=post, features=Features(
            concepts=ConceptsOptions(limit=10))).get_result()
```

The result returned in the response variable is

```
{'concepts': [], 'language': 'en', 'usage': {'features': 1, 'text_characters': 393, 'text_units': 1}}
```

**Is it a known limitation of API that I am unaware of or is there some issue with the way I am calling the API?**

Comment: Can you please clarify if the sample post you have of "Are Dostoevsky's characters ..." gives you an empty concepts array as a response.

Comment: @chughts concepts array is empty. As you can see in the output I have given in question. 
     'concepts': []

Comment: I don't get an empty concepts array for the text "Are Dostoevsky's characters ...", which beggars the question - Is the code that you are showing the code that you are actually executing? In particular which bit of your code do you output the response that shows an empty concepts array? I suspect you have a scope / initialisation problem in the code that outputs the response.

Comment: using Jupyter I just printed the `response` variable. However my code parses the variable in proper way and results were empty. Now it is showing concepts. I have shared another text that returner zero concepts just now in a comment to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54929322/1528290) below.

Answer (score 0):

For the same text I am able to get the following the as output for concepts from the API with same limits and same version date.

```
"concepts": [
    {
        "text": "Existentialism",
        "relevance": 0.988784,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Existentialism"
    },
    {
        "text": "The Brothers Karamazov",
        "relevance": 0.856152,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/The_Brothers_Karamazov"
    },
    {
        "text": "Fyodor Dostoyevsky",
        "relevance": 0.83996,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Fyodor_Dostoyevsky"
    },
    {
        "text": "Human condition",
        "relevance": 0.716108,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Human_condition"
    },
    {
        "text": "Psychology",
        "relevance": 0.687781,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Psychology"
    },
    {
        "text": "Philosophy of life",
        "relevance": 0.675628,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Philosophy_of_life"
    },
    {
        "text": "Meaning of life",
        "relevance": 0.65926,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Meaning_of_life"
    },
    {
        "text": "Human nature",
        "relevance": 0.652501,
        "dbpedia_resource": "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Human_nature"
    }
]
```

Can you pass in some wikipedia text for any famous place to verify if you get concepts returned at all in the output. Also make sure you do not set any default language while sending information to the API. NLU auto detects the language if the text is more than 100 characters in most cases. For example if you set the language to spanish (es) it might invoke the spanish concepts engine and you may get few to no results.

Comment: Texts in my data are very long so I am not posting examples, but just to give example, same script has returned concepts for over 3 thousands texts. Only about 150 were returned with no concepts. 
I am not specifying  language in parameters. Call to API is the same as posted in question.

Comment: So I have tried again and this time it returned concepts. Since I have not change my code since yesterday. I suspect Watson may be taking notes of the failures and then correcting its results. 
Here is another post that I just  tried and got zero concepts in response.

Comment: post= "No job. Never had any romantic experiences. I just have no ability / infrastructure to get through life. It's killing me. I don't want to be part of this world because I can't fit in, can't compete, can't enjoy. Why does it have to be so uncomfortable? I feel so sad on the inside. Another night. I wonder how it will ever change....will it require my effort completely? I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO FUCKING DO"